# How to get the last data in array inside a .Where() condition

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, list, linq

Im using MongoDB.

```
var dataList = _context.GetCollection<SampleCollection>();
    
var result = dataList.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Status.Last().Status == "Something");
```

I am trying to achieve this Query above. But it's giving me error below.

*`Last({document}{Status}.Select({document}{Status})) is not supported.`*

Status is a List of object. What I'm trying to achieve here is in a dataList I want to get the the latest Status object and validate it if it's Status is "Something".

Sample data from SampleCollection:

```
UserId : "UserTest123",
Status : [
   {
     ID: "1",
     Status: "Hey"
   },
   {
     ID: "1",
     Status: "Something"
   },
]
```

Comment: *But it's giving me error* - curious to know why you didn't mention the exact error message to us? It's usually the single most useful piece of debugging info for a remote assist

Comment: As it stands the query looks OK if you truly do have some list of things in `dataList` that have a Status array that is already sorted such that a call to last makes sense, and mongo can retrieve a last item. If some items will have 0 items in their status, consider `.LastOrDefault()?.Status == "Something"`

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question. The error is "
Last({document}{Status}.Select({document}{Status})) is not supported."

Comment: x.Status.LastOrDefault()?.Status still not working.

Comment: Out of curiosity (because I never worked with Mongo), does `dataList.AsQueryable().Select(x => x.Status.Last())` work? Or even more simply `dataList.AsQueryable().Last()` - if it doesn't do Last, then this approach won't work out

Comment: Yes .Last() will work if I try it on a foreach loop. But when using it inside a Where condition it doesn't seem to work

Comment: You should not have properties and subproperties named the same, that might confuse not only you but also the runtime.

Comment: Just for this example I have used the same property and subproperty. But in the original code it's Statuses and Status

Comment: Did you try adding an `OrderBy` before `Last`? Also, `Statuses` was **fine**, why'd you change it for `Status`?

Comment: I have solved the issue now. It doesn't work when it's IQueryable. But when I use .ToList() first then use the .Where() and .Last() it's working fine now. But I'm not sure if it's the best approach. It might affect time complexity.

Comment: I don't know if this is true for MongoDB, but most databases I know of do not guarantee a stable order of results if not explicitly defined using an unambiguous order by clause. So sometimes "Something" might come back last and sometimes "Hey" might come back last. This may not be evident with just a few rows (selects may appear to consistently reflect order of insertion), but this may change as data grows and the data storage or query working data gets juggled around. It may be best to put an effective date stamp on status and then use .OrderBy(...).Last() or .OrderByDescending(...).First().

Comment: See [Is natural order in MongoDB stable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63172002/is-natural-order-in-mongodb-stable) in reference to my prior comment about status order.

Comment: *But when I use .ToList() first then use the .Where() and .Last() it's working fine now* - be careful; I strongly suspect that will download the entire SampleCollection "table" (or whatever mongo calls it) into your program first..